# android write data to file internal,method in class

Tags: java, android, file, class, storage

I try to write data in a txt file, using the internal storage of android,
it works fine when i use the code directly in the "buttonClicked" function in the mainActivity.java but when i try to call the method in a class the emulator crashes. Thanks!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        // the class object ----------------------
    FileHandler myFileHandler = new FileHandler();
    public static final String FILENAME = "myFile.txt";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


   public void buttonClicked(View view) {
       // Call the method in the Filehandler Class 
       myFileHandler.saveData(FILENAME);
} ...
```

fileHandler Class

```
public class FileHandler extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();

    FileHandler() { 
    }


    void saveData(String FILENAME) {

        Log.d(TAG, FILENAME);

        try {
               OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
               outputStreamWriter.write("hallo welt");
               outputStreamWriter.close();
           }
           catch (IOException e) {
               Log.e(TAG, "File write failed: " + e.toString());
           }
    } ...
```

this works fine …

```
public void buttonClicked(View view) {



       myFileHandler.saveData(FILENAME);

        try {
               OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
               outputStreamWriter.write("hallo welt");
               outputStreamWriter.close();
           }
           catch (IOException e) {
               Log.e(TAG, "File write failed: " + e.toString());
           } 

    }
```

all the classes are imported correctly, the error from log cat

```
    11-11 11:49:22.646: E/AndroidRuntime(833): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-11 11:49:22.646: E/AndroidRuntime(833): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
11-11 11:49:22.646: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
11-11 11:49:22.646: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
11-11 11:49:22.646: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
11-11 11:49:22.646: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-11 11:49:22.646: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-11 11:49:22.646: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-11 11:49:22.646: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-11 11:49:22.646: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 11:49:22.646: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-11 11:49:22.646: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-11 11:49:22.646: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-11 11:49:22.646: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-11 11:49:22.646: E/AndroidRuntime(833): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-11 11:49:22.646: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at com.example.iLoveMyMobile.MainActivity.buttonClicked(MainActivity.java:55)
11-11 11:49:22.646: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 11:49:22.646: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-11 11:49:22.646: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
11-11 11:49:22.646: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  ... 11 more
11-11 11:49:22.646: E/AndroidRuntime(833): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-11 11:49:22.646: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileOutput(ContextWrapper.java:158)
11-11 11:49:22.646: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at com.example.iLoveMyMobile.FileHandler.saveData(FileHandler.java:36)
11-11 11:49:22.646: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Th problem is `context object became null` in

```
OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
```

Here `openFileOutput` is actually `this.openFileOutput`
So`openFileOutput` method was referring to same context of MainActivity, but when you have put in another activity it is getting context as null. You can re-write the method by passing the context parameter
eg

```
void saveData(String FILENAME, Context mContext) {

        Log.d(TAG, FILENAME);

        try {
               OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(mContext.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
               outputStreamWriter.write("hallo welt");
               outputStreamWriter.close();
           }
           catch (IOException e) {
               Log.e(TAG, "File write failed: " + e.toString());
           }
    }
```

and while calling you can write following

```
myFileHandler.saveData(FILENAME, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you're trying to use the method in the FileHandler class from MainActivity. FileHandler should not extend Activity if it's just an object you use for filesaving.

Remove extends Activity and use your Mainactivity as context to your FileHandler class.

```
    FileHandler f = new FileHandler(Mainactivity.class);
```

and then in FileHandler

```
    context.openFileOutput()
```